# FunctionCompiling lists of things

Tags: compile, function-compile, data-types

I have a compiled function that works on a *list of some atomic type* e.g. strings, but also want it to work on lists of others (e.g. integers, reals, symbols, etc).

Moreover, nothing in the code has to change, other than the Typed argument. FunctionCompile is supposed to support some polymorphism no? In pseudocode, this is what I want:

```
f = Function[Typed[in, 
   "PackedArray"::["MachineInteger" | "Real" | "String" | Symbol | ..., 1]], ... ]
```

What if any is the suggested way to achieve this?

**Update:**

@SjoerdSmit correctly states that such polymorphism does not yet exist. But watching the Compiler Design Review streams on Twitch led me to think it could work like this:

```
FunctionCompile[
 Typed[ForAllType[t, {"ListVector"::[t]} -> t]]@
  Function[list, SomethingThatWorksOnAnyList[list]]]
```

Or is it the case that `CompiledCodeFunction` can *only return one fixed type of a list?*

Comment: I don't think the polymorphic functionalities have been released yet, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I asked a question about your point, I might have been confused in thinking that a compiled function could return different types based on its argument's type

Comment: For those interested, [Live CEOing Ep 549](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mybi2KHJ8U0) discussed the design of polymorphic declarations and related topics.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct this type of polymorphism does not yet exist. At compile time the new compiler must be able to determine all of the types.

The second type of polymorphism can be used to call polymorphic functions from within other compiled code. For instance:

```
In[45]:= dec = 
 FunctionDeclaration[FirstElem, 
  Typed[ForAllType["t", {"PackedArray"["t", 1]} -> "t"]]@ 
   Function[l, l[[1]]]];

In[46]:= FunctionCompile[{dec}, 
 Function[Typed[a, "PackedArray"["Real64", 1]], FirstElem[a]]];

In[47]:= %[{1., 2., 3.}]

Out[47]= 1.
```

Comment: So it would be impossible to write a compiled run length encoding function that works on both a list of strings and a list of numbers?

Comment: @user5601 Yes it would be. Though the compiler is an area of very active development so that may change in future versions.